# Qquery, увеличение фотографии

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Добрый день! Столкнулся с такой задачей. Есть картинка

```
<a class="title-item-event" href="#">
<img src="/image/width/115/44764-1480932675.jpeg" alt="" 
data="/image/width/580/44764-1480932675.jpeg">
```

В поле `src="/image/width/115/44764-1480932675.jpeg"` это её привью, в поле ссылка на большую картинку оригинал `data="/image/width/580/44764-1480932675.jpeg">`, когда пользователь жмёт на маленькую происходит увеличение

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".title-item-event").click(function(){
        var link = $($(this).children()).attr("src");
        var full_link = $($(this).children()).attr("data");
        $($(this).children()).attr("src", full_link);
        $(".b-featuredobjects-main .item").css("height", "400px");
    });
});
```

Т.е. содержимое этих полей просто меняются. Всё работает хорошо, но есть такой вопрос: можно ли к этому увеличению сделать плавную анимацию (плавное увеличение)?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("img").click(function(){
  $(this).animate({ // http://api.jquery.com/animate/
    width: "256px",
    height: "256px",
  }, 1500 );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="title-item-event" href="#">
  <img src="http://podckaska.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/kalendula-solnechnyj-cvetok-dlya-krasoty-i-zdorovya.jpg" width="128px" height="128px">
</a>
```